# Run Java code before server stops

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring MVC project and I want to serialize some objects before Tomcat/whole app is stopping. I managed to handle the startup by implementing ApplicationListener.
How can I handle the server/app stop event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways :
- If your application is in servlet container(e.g. tomcat) , you can register `ServletContextListener` and implement `contextDestroyed` event.
- If it is desktop application , you can add shutdown hook `Runtime.addShutdownHook()` which will be called just before destroying the JVM.